# Excel - IF function using a wildcard

Tags: excel

I have been working on a spreadsheet in excel and I have encountered a problem in which I am not able to solve. I have attempted everything to my knowledge and performed research on what I was able to find online. I am attempting to use an IF statement to automatically populate a cell with a "Department ID" number after selecting the Department from a Data Validation drop down list. After all of my research, the most progress I made was with the function:

```
=IF(E2="*",VLOOKUP(E2,'Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!$C$2:$D$31,2),"No Department")
```

In the example above, "E2" is the cell containing the drop down list of Department Names where I am attempting to search from.

My issue is that when using this function, I always return "No Department" in the output cell where my function is located, meaning my IF function is always proving to be false. I am never able to successfully search and output the correct Department ID from the Department selected in the Data validation drop down list. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried that solution @ScottCraner but I wasn't able to get the result I need. This changed my output from "No Department" to #N/A

Comment: Then your VLOOKUP is not working.  The IF() returned TRUE.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I see. If I may ask, why does my function work with =IF(E2="*",...)? I understand #N/A is a VLOOKUP error, but I'm just confused why it works with one logical test and not the other.

Comment: Your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is an approximate match and the lookup column ('Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!$C:$C) must be in ascending order. [edit] Use `VLOOKUP(E2,'Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!$C$2:$D$31,2, FALSE)`

Comment: Wildcards do not work inside an IF function.  See here for a list of function that support wildcards: http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm

Comment: I appreciate the advice and suggestions @ScottCraner I'll be sure to keep that page bookmarked for future spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is an approximate match and the lookup column ('Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!$C:$C) must be in ascending order.

I would suggest changing error control to a wrapping [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) and using FALSE for an exact match on the VLOOKUP.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2, 'Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!$C$2:$D$31, 2, FALSE),"No Department")
```

If your lookup column is to the right of your 'value-to-return' column, use

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!C:C, MATCH(B2, 'Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!D:D, 0)), "no department")
```

[VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) always uses the left-most column to lookup and returns the value form the right. To lookup on the right and return from a column to the left, you need an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

Comment: This brought my return back to "No Department" I understand completely what the function is saying, I am just baffled as to why my result is still false.

Comment: Well, your VLOOKUP is not working correctly. Could be a number of reasons. Consder posting a redacted copy of the worksheet for public access so it can be properly examined.

Comment: I have my document updated and ready for public access. Please excuse my ignorance, but how am I able to post the document on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Upload into any **publicly accessible** file repository (google-drive, microsoft cloud, dropbox, etc) and post the link back here.

Comment: I see, I apologize, I misunderstood. 
[Public Version of Document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3E18XJt-or6OHNXWHRGX3RjdFk)
There was a bit of company sensitive material I needed to sensor and remove. However, this is the base of my document.

Comment: Use `=IFERROR(INDEX('Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!C:C, MATCH(B2, 'Locate-Dept-AcctNum'!D:D, 0)), "no department")`. VLOOKUP always uses the left-most column to lookup and returns the value from the right. To lookup on the right and return on the left, you need an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

Comment: That took care of the issue @Jeeped thank you! For future reference, should I change the order of the table in order to use a VLOOKUP, or stick to the INDEX/MATCH function?

Comment: INDEX/MATCH is actually a more efficient calculation. I use them even when VLOOKUP would provide the correct results but I'm 'old school'. You should definitely keep both methods in your repetoire of commonly used functions.